# Reversing the output of a while sequence in python 3?

Tags: python

The assignment is to write a program that prints a diagram of the function 2^n, as follows:

```
*
**
****
********
****************
********************************
****************
********
****
**
*
```

I was able to program the second half (from 2^6 downward in the example), but I don't know how to reverse the `while` function to create the first half. This is my code thus far:

```
import math
n=None
while n is None:
    try:
        n=input("Enter an integer for the power of two you wish to represent: ")
        n=int(n)
    except ValueError:
        print("That is not an integer. Please try again.")
    else:
        while n>=0:
            amt=(math.pow(2,n))
            print('*'*int(amt))
            n=int(n)-1
```

which, when I input 6, outputs

```
********************************
****************
********
****
**
*
```

So how do I get it to do the first half as well?

Comment: you wrote the first diagram belongs to 2^n, but it is not. I guess something is missing you trying to explain.

Comment: The first diagram does correspond. 2^0 is the first line, 2^1 is the second line, etc.

Comment: yes i've noticed, but when it comes to half of it, it goes to downward. Are you trying to figure that out ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to do!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use while function. From my point of view, for loop is better here.
So you can e.g. use your code in two for loops, one ascending, and second one descending.

```
for power in range(n):
    amt=(math.pow(2,power))
    print('*'*int(amt))
for power in range(n-1)[::-1]:
    amt=(math.pow(2,power))
    print('*'*int(amt))
```

Comment: This works, but I'm very new to coding and really trying to understand its mechanics. Would you mind explaining to me what the 4th line of your code ("for power...") does and why? I don't understand the n-1. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: range(n) creates you a sequence, you can interpret it as [0,1,2,3,4] if n equals 5. `for power` means "for each one element from sequence, that I call 'power'" so in first iteration power equals 0, in second one 1, etc. Second for loop does the same, but for n = 5, you generate [0,1,2,3] (because of n-1), and then you reverse it by [::-1], so you iterate by [3,2,1,0]. Is it understandable?

Comment: You may find it easier to understand as `reversed(range(n-1))`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import math

def draw(n):
    i = 0;
    while i <= n:
        d = i
        if i > n /2:
            d = n - i;
        print("*" * int(math.pow(2,d)))
        i+=1
draw(12)
```

For n = 12;

```
*
**
****
********
****************
********************************
****************************************************************
********************************
****************
********
****
**
*
```

Comment: What does Def and draw do?

Comment: in python, Def defines functions. So draw is a function. You can pass to draw function and print starts.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the resultant values ​​and store them in a list and then reverse the two half of a list to have the expected result

```
import math
n=None
while n is None:
    try:
        n=input("Enter an integer for the power of two you wish to     represent: ")
        n=int(n)
    except ValueError:
        print("That is not an integer. Please try again.")
    else:
        lst = [math.pow(2,abs(r)) for r in range(0-n, n)]
        lst = lst[len(lst)/2:] + lst[:len(lst)/2+1]
        for item in lst:
           print('*'*int(item))
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but as I have yet to use the for loop, I think I will go for Grysik's answer for expanding my practices :)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this in one loop by something like this:

```
        i=n*-1
        while i<=n:
          x =n-abs(i)
          amt=(math.pow(2,x))
          print('*'*int(amt))
          i=i+1
```

Comment: What does the abs function do? Can you explain this loop to me like I'm a stupid person?

Comment: The function abs returns the absolute value of a number. -5 returns 5.